# Python UDP set TTL with sendmsg [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Tags: python, sockets, udp, ttl

My OS is virtualized 4.13.0-39-generic #44-Ubuntu. I'm using python3.6.

What I am trying to do is send UDP packet with setted TTL, using `sendmsg`. But, I still got Errno mentioned above. Regular `setsockopt` with IP_TTL and then `sendto` works fine, but I have to use `sendmsg` if it is possible of course.

My code:

```
Ancdata = [(socket.SOL_IP, socket.IP_TTL, bytes([1])]
Flags=0
Msg=[''.encode()]
Address = ('10.0.0.0',2222)
socket.sendmsg(Msg, Ancdata, Flags, Address)
```

Note: `sendmsg` with empty list `ancdata` works fine

Comment: So, what is errno 22?

Comment: Well I guess it is invalid ancillary data passed to the sendmsg. I tried many diffrent options, socket.IPPROTO_IP instead of socket.SOL_IP or use ipv6 and UNICAST_HOPS, but results are the same. I couldn't find info that it is possible to set TTL with sendmsg, but for sure TOS can be, so why not TTL too

Comment: Just feed that error to a random search engine or into the search field above.

Comment: Errno 22 it's an OS error number, so it can be related to any invalid argument passed to any function, not only those from socket library. I tried searching it, really, but i couldn't find anything connected with socket.sendmsg() or setting TTL

Comment: idk if this is your problem, but: `socket.socket.setsockopt` expects its third argument to be an integer or a buffer object. In the case of a buffer, it's "up to the caller to ensure that the bytestring contains the proper bits" - from the Python3 documentation. So, you could be seeing this because `bytes([1]) == b'\x01'` - meaning it's only one byte wide. Try passing just `1` and see if that gets you anywhere.